# Python bytes(...) on custom class

Tags: python

I have a custom class in python which I need to pass to an external API. The API only requires to be able to invoke `bytes(...)` on my class.

My question is, how can I decide the behavior of invoking `bytes()` on my custom python class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can give your custom class a [`__bytes__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bytes__):

> Called by `bytes` to compute a byte-string representation of an object. This should return a `bytes` object.

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __bytes__(self):
...         return b'This is a bytes result for this instance'
...
>>> bytes(Foo())
b'This is a bytes result for this instance'
```

Comment: is there a standard way for parsing an instance of a class from bytes? i.e. the inverse of __bytes__?

Comment: @JordanMackie: no, `__bytes__` returns an arbitrary bytes value, not a representation of a specific class instance.

Comment: @JordanMackie: see https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/serialization/ for serialisation options, there is no 'standard' way for object serialisation.